# Como hacer un Slideshow de HTML en un archivo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer un slideshow de HTML como este https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp en un archivo PHP. En ese archivo se muestran varias imagenes como fondo de etiquetas div, y quería cambiarlo para que se vieran en un carrusel o slideshow. El problema es que despues de todo el código no aparece nada del slideshow, ni siquiera las imágenes y no estoy seguro que hice mal de todo. De seguro son los links, pero no se como arreglarlo. En el codigo del archivo PHP se mantienen las imagenes de las etiquetas div y el código del slideshow. Tambien puse dos veces el link de slideshow.css, uno dentro de la etiqueta php y otro dentro del head de HTML porque no estoy seguro cual era el correcto.

El código del archivo PHP.

```
<?php
  $titulo = "Turismo";
  $seccion ="hacer";
  include('app/header-template.php');
  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='public/css/slideshow.css'  />";
?>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public\css\slideshow.css">
<script language="JavaScript" src="public\js\slideshowcodigo.js"></script>
</head>

  <header class="header-rural"></header>

  <section class="container">
    


<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1 class="text-center">Turismo </h1>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <p class="lead">Una forma diferente de revivir nuestras costumbres, es hacerlo en contacto con la naturaleza, los animales y las actividades de campo. Lobos tiene sus tranqueras abiertas, para disfrutar de un paseo a caballo, la gastronomía típica, de las costumbres de los pueblos rurales y sus pintorescas calles.
</p><p class="lead">La oferta se conforma por estancias, complejos para pasar un día de campo, actividades tradicionales en localidades rurales, recorrida por los caminos reales que unen a nuestros pueblos y sus típicos almacenes de campo aún vigentes. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    

  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="dSlides fade">
    <img src="public/img/turismo/rural/2.jpg" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="dSlides fade">
    <img src="public/img/turismo/rural/1.jpg" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="dSlides fade">
    <img src="public/img/turismo/rural/3.jpg" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
    
    <a class="ant" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="sig" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

    <section class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/2.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/1.jpg')"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/3.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/4.jpg')"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/5.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/6.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/7.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 actividades" style="background-image: url('public/img/turismo/rural/8.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
    </section>



  </section>
  

<script>

var sIndex=1;
showSlides(sIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(sIndex +=n);
}

functionCurrentSlide(n){
showSlides(sIndex =n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides= document.getElementsByClassName("dSlides");
if (n>slides.length) {sIndex=1}
if (n<1) {sIndex=slides.legth}
for (i=0; i<slides.length, i++) {
slides[i].style.display="none";
}
//sIndex++;
slides[sIndex-1].style.display="block";
//setTimeout(showSlides,2000);

}

</script>
<?php include('app/footer-template.php') ?>
```

el código del css del slideshow

```
@charset "utf-8"; /* CSS Document */

*{box-sizing:border-box}

.slideshow-container { max-width:100%; position:relative; margin:auto; } .dSlides { display:none; }

.ant, .sig { cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:50%; width:auto; margin-top:-22px; padding:16px; color:white; font-weigth:bold; font-size:18px; transition:0.6s ease; border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0; user-select:none; }

.sig { right:0; border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; }

.ant:over, .sig:hover { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }

.fade {
-webkit-animation-name:fade;
-webkit-animation-duration:1.6s; animation-name:fade; animation-duration:1.5s; }

@webkit-keyframes fade { from {opacity:.4} to {opacity:1} } @keyframes fade { from {opacity:.4} to {opacity:1} }
```

Comment: Tienes que recordar que estamos hablando de 4 cosas diferentes acá... html (la base), css, javascript y php. Primero que nada, logra implementar el slide/carrousel. Luego piensa como pasarle las imagenes que quieres. Por que para hacer el slide, no necesitas el php... el php es para traer información a través de una conexión.

Comment: Esto lo digo por que con tu codigo no he podido hacer funcionar el slide, a pesar de agregarle imagenes personalmente. (luego de haber corregido otras cosas)

Comment: ¿Tu script `app/header-template.php` ya incluye todas las etiquetas del encabezado HTML?, es decir, si ahí tienes `<head>...</head>`, entonces estás generando mal el código HTML, porque después lo vuelves a enviar.